# Filter SQL Table in PowerApps Repeating Gallery

Tags: gallery, repeat, powerapps

Morning All,

I have been struggling with this issue for over a week and have not been able to find a solution that actually works.  My requirement is to use a SQL table to search for an Employee number and populate a 'repeating gallery item' with the Employee number and the First and Last Name of the Employee.

App > OnStart:
`Set(varAddItem, Value(Last(colSearchID).Employee) +1); Collect(colSearchID, {Employee:0, FirstName:"", LastName:""});`

I'm using a Text Input for a 'Search Box' for the Employee number search.

The 'OnSelect' for the Add Item icon:
`Set(varAddItem, Value(Last(colSearchID).Employee) +1); Collect(colSearchID, {Employee:0, FirstName:"", LastName:""});`

'Items' property for the IDSearchGallery:
colSearchID

This combination creates the repeating item but does **NOT** populate the gallery text input controls for the Employee number (txtID) or the FirstName and LastName (txtName = Concatenate(ThisItem.FirstName & " " & ThisItem.LastName))

[Repeating Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfwpP.png)

When I change the Gallery Items to: Filter(colSearchID, Employee = Value(IDSearch.Text)), the repeating section stops working.

When I change the Gallery Items to: Filter(bPREH, Employee = Value(IDSearch.Text)), the filter works, but the repeating section does not.

[Gallery Filter w/SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9U1L.png)

How can I combine the two to obtain the Employee information and create multiple items in the repeating gallery?

Comment: Patti what is the Default property for txtID? txtName is correct since you are collecting empty values with both App.OnStart and Button.OnSelect.

Comment: @mmikesy90, thank you very much for responding.  The Default property for txtID is ThisItem.Employee, Employee is a number field in the SQL table.